# In OpenCV bound with Python, why the NumPy function can be used without it being called?

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

So, for example like below simple code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread(image.bmp)
imageCopy = image.copy()
```

In above example, I just copied the image by using one of the functions from NumPy module although I didn't write something like `np.copy()`, which means I didn't even call the `copy()` function from the NumPy module. At least, this is what I understand from my humble knowledge since I am still new to this. Why is this? Is it because OpenCV will automatically use the NumPy module if it is ever about array?

Comment: Do `type(image)`, I'm pretty sure OpenCV returns NumPy arrays where one would normally have a `Mat` object in C++.  so you get to use NumPy's ndarray's methods because it is an ndarray that was returned to you.

Comment: `.copy` is a method of the object `image`.  Review the distinction between methods and functions in Python.

Comment: @Jaime Done it, it does return `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`. Means that, the openCV will always use the NumPy's ndarray's method?

Comment: @hpaulj I already reviewed it. Basically, method is a function of a class isn't it? But I still can't really relate it with my confusion right now. Basically, object `image', which is read by the module cv2 is from NumPy class? I don't really know how to explain clearly my confusion. Pardon me. Will try to do more study regarding this thing.

Comment: `cv2` must be importing `numpy` as well, for its own use, and to create this return object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call the `np.copy` function : you called the copy method of the image object that `cv2.imread` returned.

If you type `print (dir(image))`, you'll probably see the copy method that was actually called. This method might (or not) use the `np.copy` function for its own processing, but it's outside of your control.

Comment: Did that. Get bunch of list but didn't find `np.copy`. But by typing printing `type(image)`, I got `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`. Is it means the returned value will always use the method of NumPy since it is a NumPy type object?

Comment: it means the image is actually a `numpy.ndarray`. You will never find `np.copy` as a method name, you'll actually find the copy method of the object (its full name would be `numpy.ndarray.copy`, as documented here : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html#numpy.ndarray.copy )

Comment: OK thanks. I think this is somehow clear me up. Will read more about this.